# F# Recursion vs Iteration speed/overhead

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, f#

I've been messing around a bit with Riccardo Terrell's Akka.NET Fractal demo (https://github.com/rikace/akkafractal) to try and understand it. (It's great, btw)

One thing I tried as a minor challenge for myself was to rewrite some bits of it in a more functional way. I've got it to work but it's **much** slower than the original.

Here's (more or less) the original Mandelbrot Set calculation adapted for testing:

```fs
    let mandelbrotSet (xp : int) (yp : int) (w : int) (h :int) (width : int) (height : int)
                  (maxr : float) (minr : float) (maxi : float) (mini : float) : List<int> =

    let mutable zx = 0.
    let mutable zy = 0.
    let mutable cx = 0.
    let mutable cy = 0.
    let mutable xjump = ((maxr - minr) / ( float width))

    let yjump = ((maxi - mini) / (float height))

    let mutable tempzx = 0.
    let loopmax = 1000
    let mutable loopgo = 0

    let outputList: int list = List.empty

    for x = xp to (xp + w) - 1 do
        cx <- (xjump * float x) - abs(minr)

        for y = yp to (yp + h) - 1 do
            zx <- 0.
            zy <- 0.
            cy <- (yjump * float y) - abs(mini)
            loopgo <- 0

            while (zx * zx + zy * zy <= 4. && loopgo < loopmax) do
                loopgo <- loopgo + 1
                tempzx <- zx
                zx <- (zx * zx) - (zy * zy) + cx
                zy <- (2. * tempzx * zy) + cy

            (List.append outputList [loopgo]) |> ignore

    outputList
```

And here's my version with the recursive mbCalc function doing the work:

```fs
let mandelbrotSetRec (xp : int) (yp : int) (w : int) (h :int) (width : int) (height : int)
    (maxr : float) (minr : float) (maxi : float) (mini : float) : List<int> =

    let xjump = ((maxr - minr) / (float width))
    let yjump = ((maxi - mini) / (float height))
    let loopMax = 1000
    let outputList: int list = List.empty

    let rec mbCalc(zx:float, zy:float, cx:float, cy:float, loopCount:int) = 
        match (zx * zx + zy * zy), loopCount with //The square of the magnitude of z
          | a,b when a > 4. || b = loopMax -> loopCount
          | _ -> mbCalc((zx * zx) - (zy * zy) + cx, (2. * zx * zy) + cy, cx, cy, loopCount+1) //iteration is the next value of z^2+c

    [|0..w-1|] //For each x...
        |> Array.map (fun x ->  let cx = (xjump * float (x+xp) - abs(minr))
                                [|0..h-1|] ///and for each y...
                                    |> Array.map (fun y -> let cy = (yjump * float (y+yp) - abs(mini))
                                                           let mbVal = mbCalc(0., 0., cx, cy,0)  //Calculate the number of iterations to convergence (recursively)
                                                           List.append outputList [mbVal]))|>ignore

    outputList
```

Is this just to be expected, pointlessly loading up an Actor with a load of recursive calls, or am I just doing something very inefficiently? Any pointers gratefully received!

If you want to run them then here's a little test script:

```
let xp = 1500
let yp = 1500
let w = 200
let h = 200
let width = 4000
let height = 4000

let timer1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
timer1.Start()
let ref = mandelbrotSet xp yp w h width height 0.5 -2.5 1.5 -1.5
timer1.Stop()

let timer2 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
timer2.Start()
let test = mandelbrotSetRec xp yp w h width height 0.5 -2.5 1.5 -1.5
timer2.Stop

timer1.ElapsedTicks;;
timer2.ElapsedTicks;;
ref = test;;
```

EDIT: As per Philip's answer below, I added the list output quickly (too quickly!) to make something that ran in a script without requiring any imports. Here's the code to return the image:

```fs
    let mandelbrotSetRec (xp : int) (yp : int) (w : int) (h :int) (width : int) (height : int)
        (maxr : float) (minr : float) (maxi : float) (mini : float) : Image<Rgba32> =

        let img = new Image<Rgba32>(w, h)
        let xjump = ((maxr - minr) / (float width))
        let yjump = ((maxi - mini) / (float height))
        let loopMax = 1000

        //Precalculate the possible colour list
        let palette = List.append  ([0..loopMax - 1] |> List.map(fun c -> Rgba32(byte(c % 32 * 7), byte(c % 128 * 2), byte(c % 16 * 14)))) [Rgba32.Black]

        let rec mbCalc(zx:float, zy:float, cx:float, cy:float, loopCount:int) = 
            match (zx * zx + zy * zy), loopCount with //The square of the magnitude of z
              | a,b when a > 4. || b = loopMax -> loopCount
              | _ -> mbCalc((zx * zx) - (zy * zy) + cx, (2. * zx * zy) + cy, cx, cy, loopCount+1) //iteration is the next value of z^2+c

        [|0..w-1|] //For each x...
            |> Array.map (fun x ->  let cx = (xjump * float (x+xp) - abs(minr))
                                    [|0..h-1|] ///and for each y...
                                        |> Array.map (fun y -> let cy = (yjump * float (y+yp) - abs(mini))
                                                               let mbVal = mbCalc(0., 0., cx, cy,0)  //Calculate the number of iterations to convergence (recursively)
                                                               img.[x,y] <- palette.[mbVal]))|>ignore
        img
```

Comment: Mandelbrot my .old friend. Anyway, in my experience a well written tail recursive function in F# is my preferred wait to iterate. If you use a tool like `dnSpy` you can analyze the generated code and if you done it correctly you will see that the generated code is indeed a loop. It usually contains some weirdness but overall the jitter seems to be able to eliminate the unnecessary variables. One benefit of tail recusion in F# is that AFAIK it's the only way to iterate towards 0 properly eliminating the need of an extra register that sometimes can give a bit of speed up

Comment: Also, the mutable loop is inefficient in itself. There are many optimizations that can be applied to it.

Comment: Typically the JIT optimizes away any additional overhead from recursion as per your comment. There are some cases where excessive emission of the .tail instruction can hinder performance, but this is also pretty much solved for .NET 5. So in other words, free perf is coming!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, both functions return `[]` so there is no mandlebrot set being returned even if it's correctly calculated. `List.append` returns a list, it doesn't mutate an existing one.

Using a quick BenchmarkDotNet program below, where each function is in its own module:

```
open BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes
open BenchmarkDotNet.Running
open ActorTest

[<MemoryDiagnoser>]
type Bench() =
    let xp = 1500
    let yp = 1500
    let w = 200
    let h = 200
    let width = 4000
    let height = 4000    

    [<Benchmark(Baseline=true)>]
    member _.Mutable() =
        Mutable.mandelbrotSet xp yp w h width height 0.5 -2.5 1.5 -1.5

    [<Benchmark>]
    member _.Recursive() =
        Recursive.mandelbrotSet xp yp w h width height 0.5 -2.5 1.5 -1.5

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Bench>()
    printfn "%A" summary
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Your code gave these results:

```
|    Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD |    Gen 0 |    Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|---------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|------:|--------:|---------:|---------:|------:|----------:|
|   Mutable | 1.356 ms | 0.0187 ms | 0.0166 ms |  1.00 |    0.00 | 406.2500 |        - |     - |   1.22 MB |
| Recursive | 2.558 ms | 0.0303 ms | 0.0283 ms |  1.89 |    0.03 | 613.2813 | 304.6875 |     - |   2.13 MB |
```

I noticed that you're using `Array.map` but there's no results being captured anywhere, so changing that to `Array.iter` got your code to be nearly the same:

```
|    Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Ratio |    Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|---------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|------:|---------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|   Mutable | 1.515 ms | 0.0107 ms | 0.0094 ms |  1.00 | 406.2500 |     - |     - |   1.22 MB |
| Recursive | 1.652 ms | 0.0114 ms | 0.0101 ms |  1.09 | 607.4219 |     - |     - |   1.82 MB |
```

This difference can probably be explained by the additional allocations done with the mapping calls. Allocations are expensive, especially when it's larger arrays, so it's best to avoid them if possible. Exact timings will differ from machine to machine but I'd expect a similar before/after ratio when using BenchmarkDotNet.

This could probably be further optimized by avoiding the list allocations and pre-allocating a list or array that you fill in. The same is true for the iterative call. Also looping through a `Span<'T>` will be faster than an array since it elides a bounds check, but you'd probably have to change the shape of your code a lot to do that.

Lastly, always use a statistical benchmarking tool like BenchmarkDotNet to measure performance in microbenchmarks like this. Quick scripts are fine as a starting point, but they're no substitute for a tool that accounts for execution time variability on a machine.

Comment: So, to more succinctly answer the question in the title, would you conclude that... there is no intrinsic overhead? It all depends on allocations, and algorithm complexity? Or does the function call stack inevitably become a bottleneck in F# when using recursive functions?

Comment: There is unlikely to be any overhead from recursive function calls, yes.